# In R sparkly, When transferring big dataframe to Spark ,the function 'copy_to' is very slow

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

in R sparklyr, when i use 'copy_to' copy data from R to Spark ,it's very slow.
Is there any way for copy big dataframe for R to Spark. Thanks.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(arrow)

sc <- spark_connect(master = 'local')
rdataframe_tbl <- copy_to(sc,rdataframe,'rdataframe')
```